# Cython - What Makes My Program Slow and How to Speed It Up?

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to speed up my cython program but I get an error on everything that I add. Does anyone know what can I do?

Here is the code:

```
cpdef char breaker(str a): 
       cdef list strings = list("abcčćdđefghijklmnoprsštuvzžqwxy1234567890ABCČĆDĐEFGHIJKLMNOPRSŠTUVZŽQWXY")
       cdef int i
       cdef int b = 0
       cdef str string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6, string7, string8
       cdef str password
       for i in range(len(strings)):
              string1 = strings[i]
              for i in range(len(strings)):
                     string2 = strings[i]
                     for i in range(len(strings)):
                            string3 = strings[i]
                            for i in range(len(strings)):
                                   string4 = strings[i]
                                   for i in range(len(strings)):
                                          string5 = strings[i]
                                          for i in range(len(strings)):
                                                 string6 = strings[i]
                                                 for i in range(len(strings)):
                                                        string7 = strings[i]
                                                        for i in range(len(strings)):
                                                               string8 = strings[i]
                                                               output = string1 + string2 +string3 + string4 + string5 + string6 + string7 + string8
                                                               if a == output:
                                                                      password = output
                                                                      quit()

                                                               if b >= 100000:
                                                                      b = 0
                                                                      print(output)

                                                               else:
                                                                      b += 1


       return password
```

`print(output)` is not neccessary line, please let me know if that can slow down the program. Here is the image of html file that shows what parts of the program are slower(yellow lines) and what are faster(white lines):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLn88.png

I am new to cython and this program is just test for future bigger projects. Thanks in advenced!

Comment: I'd start by coming up with a way of avoiding that level of loop nesting. It will not speed up the code, but more people will actually have a look at it.

Comment: Even if you assume each iteration takes a nanosecond (and it definetly takes significantly more) it will take take over 200 hours to complete...

Comment: @snakecharmerb you could use `itertools.product` but it's not really going to speed things up, and in any case, the problem here is combinatorial explosion which that doesn't avoid, it just lets you write it succinctly

Answer (score 1):

You are brute forcing 72^8 = 722204136308736 password combinations. It is bound to take its sweet little time.

(Also please don't use the same iterator "i" for all your nested loops)

Comment: I imagine using the same iterator will help with the speed (if not getting the correct answer)

Comment: Interesting observation @DavidW,  I don't really see how it would, but I'm not that well versed in cython. (I imagine it would be easier to correctly compile-optimize the loops if they each ran on their own integer, but   I see that you answer a lot of Cython questions, so I am just going to assume you know something I don't )

Comment: @DavidW not really, nothing is going to make a material difference here, even if you assume each iteration only takes a nanosecond (it's going to take significantly more), 72**8 nanoseconds is over 8 days

Comment: It was a slightly jokey comment based on the idea that the inner loop will run in full, set `i` to the final value, and then all the other loops will register as done without doing any iterations. It wasn't meant to be taken seriously anyway

Comment: Thank you all, I will try to reduce the number of loops

Comment: @Marko, if you have an 8 char password length, I don't think you can really reduce the number of loops.  There is a lot written online about the topic, but basically you want to test more likely combinations first.    Also what happens when password a is 6 or 7 letters?

Comment: @DavidW, I should have gotten that - in fact it is a type of "jokey" comment that I probably often make myself. :)

Comment: @vivibleman, the passwords that I check have 8 letters, this is made for specific type of password

Comment: @DavidW ah, you meant `i` as the iterator.

Comment: @Marko the issue isn't the *number of loops*. The issue is your approach, which is brute force.